# SQL select joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

If I have a table with the following data in MySQL:

```
id       Name       Value
1          A          4
1          A          5
1          B          8
2          C          9
```

how do I get it into the following format?
is that even possible?

```
id         Column   Column   Column    Column   Column    Column
1            A        4         A        5         B        8
2            c        9
```

Comment: If you could explain what is your logic for this output that would be helpful.  Why  there is only A and C separate in one column and B in another, 4 and 9 in one column and 5 and 8 in separate columns

Comment: i have a table with active projects in my work , in another table i have updates on those projects, with the columns: date and comments and im trying to view all the updates with the dates and comments in just 1 row with the id project

Comment: Have you considered CONCAT() function? As I understand you don't have a fixed column count so if you return a string merged with a specific delimiter and parse it back in the code side could be usefull.

Comment: You could do this with a stored procedure but it would almost certainly be significantly easier on the application side.

Comment: There an answer here for you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```